# Cut out extra lines only when present. Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Okay so I have a list of addresses and next them there is a port number. The thing is that isn't always true. For example I have this list:

```
www.google.com:80
www.gmail.com:8080
www.yahoo.com
www.msn.com:443
www.amazon.com
www.apple.com
www.hotmail.com
```

The thing I want to do is go through the text file that holds this list line by line and cut out the address and if there is a port number after the `.com` then cut that port number out and store it in a variable. This is what I tried:

```
for each in `cat address.txt`; do
    f_address=$each
    f_port=`echo $each | cut -d":" -f2`

    if [[ "$f_address" == *:* ]]; then
        address=`echo $f_address | cut -d":" -f1`
    else
        address=$f_address
    fi

    if [ "$f_port" = "*" ]; then
        port=$f_port
    else
        port="443"
    fi
```

When this is run it doesn't take what is after the `:` when needed instead it just makes it `443`.

Comment: Wait, first you do `if [[ "$f_address" == *:* ]]` with double `==`, then you do ` if [ "$f_port" = "*" ];` with just one `=`? Also, the `= *`does not work like that, just test against not empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with this:

```
while IFS=: read host port; do
   : ${port:=443}  # assign default value
   echo host=$host
   echo port=$port
done < address.txt
```

Comment: this is all being run through one for loop which is reading the context off of a file with the `address:port`. The port however isn't always there and for when it isn't, I want to default it to 443.

Comment: But I need the port and address variables to be in that one for loop. Other wise I get more results than expected. I understand that for this given problem it would work but I still want to approach it the if/else statement path.

Comment: The variables are available inside the loop and are assigned for exactly one iteration of the loop.  I do not understand your concern.  I've edited the code to explicitly assign a default.

Comment: Okay sorry about that. That was my mistake. I could just move everything inside this while loop and it would still work.